# How to write a response (type Response) in a Conn in GO?

Tags: go, webserver, response

I'm making a webserver in go and I need to give the response form the website to the client.
this in the part of my code where i receive the response:

```
            client := http.Client{}
            resp, err := client.Do(request)
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err.Error())
            }
```

The Do(request) returns a Response type and I need to send this response to the client (conn). I saw a method in conn type the writes data in the connection but it only accept bytes and i couldn't convert the response in bytes. I need to send the body, status and headers,can the conn.Write([]bytes) do that? How can I send this response to my client?

Comment: Why do you have a conn (I'm guessing a `net.Conn`?) instead of an `http.ResponseWriter`?

Comment: the conn is the connection that i receive from the method Accept(). It has a method Write where I can write data and send to the client. I receive a response and a need to send it to the client (that the infos is in the connection)

Comment: my question is: how can i send the response to the client (I mean, put in the browser the response)

Comment: If you're making a "web server", and the client is a browser, I don't understand why you don't just use an http.Server? The http package already knows how to properly format an http response.

Comment: because my server can receive others connections. I need to response a specific connection.

Comment: the infos about the client are in the net.Conn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http.Response` has a [`Write`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Write) method, which writes the contents of the response to an `io.Writer` in HTTP/1.X format.

This will write everything in the response verbatim, so you may need to remove/modify headers first to suit your needs.

```
err = resp.Write(conn)
```

Comment: I tried but the http.response doesn't have this method. The http.ResponseWrite has but I think it doens't make the same thing.

Comment: I saw in the documentation that it has this method but i can't call it. func (r *Response) Write(w io.Writer) error

Comment: It works! It was another error in the last case, Thanks very much!!